# Angularjs json ng-repeat displays items properties only with manual iterator

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I'm getting json from some web service and displaying it with ng-repeat but i can't seem to display item properties.

```
<ul>
    <li data-ng-repeat="item in itemList">
            <p>{{item}}</p>
    </li>
</ul>
```

This works and will display all json

```
<ul>
    <li data-ng-repeat="item in itemList">
            <p>{{item.name}}</p>
    </li>
</ul>
```

This doesnt work.

```
<ul>
    <li data-ng-repeat="item in itemList">
            <p>{{item[0].name}}</p>
    </li>
</ul>
```

This works but will only display 1 item.

I just started working with angular and i feel i'm missing something becouse of it, if needed i'll try to post a jfiddle of a sample.

**UPDATE**

I'm trying to get twitch.tv stream info

https://github.com/justintv/Twitch-API/blob/master/v2_resources/streams.md#get-streams

raw json from 2 streams, what i get from the first example

http://pastebin.com/bQLqu9BR

**UPDATE 2**

my code

http://plnkr.co/edit/3eOZ598zt2hkrJcsOLhP

Comment: Show us the raw json data

Comment: updated with json data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmmm... I seem to be able to work with the sample data you provided.

See the following:

http://plnkr.co/edit/M3TQ4qI1DJPtgv6jCQLy?p=preview

Snippet:

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="item in srcData">
    <p ng-bind="item.game"></p>
    <p ng-bind="item.channel.display_name"></p>
    <p ng-bind="item.channel.url"></p>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Ahh ok.  So in your updated plunk you're pushing `list.streams` into `srcData`, which is initialized to an array.  So what you're effectively doing is adding the array elements of `list.streams` as the first element of `srcData`.  Here's another plunk where I just replace `srcData` with `list.streams`.  Not sure if this approach could work for you. http://plnkr.co/edit/8iMBFZPK3lqmyoPl7Tob

Comment: Oh and here's another plunk in case you have to build up `srcData`. Use `concat` instead of `push`. http://plnkr.co/edit/DXZSQQi5qjGQXXBsVkWD

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to include an index for each item to display its properties, every item knows its index number and you can access it using the $index variable.

Check this out:

http://plnkr.co/edit/ECyyFYVupVG7mKqwsGaB

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="item in itemList">
    <a href="">{{$index}}</a>
    <p>
      Game: {{item.game}}
    </p>
    <p>
      Channel Name: {{item.channel.name}}
    </p>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: can you check out my plnkr code under update 2 and say whats wrong.

Comment: You are pushing `list.streams` array inside `$scope.srcData`array, so although the `list.streams`contains 3 elements the `$scope.srcData`array only have 1 (which is the other array) and that's why ng-repeat only displays 1 element. You can just assign `$scope.srcData = list.streams` instead of pushing it.